# How do I get table-like formatting in a textbox or textarea?

Tags: html, formatting

I'm using TinyMCE textareas or textboxes for an event logger app, and I need the text to be formatted a certain way.  Something like this:

[image]

I can't figure out how to do this without a table, which I cannot nest in the textarea or textbox.  Any suggestions?

Comment: is it true that you want this so that the text can be scrollable? if so you can put in the text inside a table, and then this table inside a div, and make the div style="overflow:auto" or style="overflow:scroll"

Comment: You could have a table inside TinyMCE, but... do you want all text to be editable?

Comment: Jian, I want the column/spacing for the date on the left, and the indentation for all the accompanying text, primarily.

lonut, TinyMCE is implemented as a textarea or textbox so I can't embed a table.  But yes, the text needs to be editable.

I knew I should have gone to truck driving school...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot -layout- content in a textbox or textarea. You want to either go for TinyMCE as an iframe (where layout is broken relatively easy), or create separate inputfields for dates and logs (and layout using html/css).

Answer (score 1):

TinyMCE has a table plugin that you can use. Have you tried that?

Search for "tinymce table plugin". Your example seems to be a 3x2 table.

Comment: That looks interesting...  I'll check it out, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to look into the [TinyMCE template plugin](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:Plugins/template).

Like Jeff Yang mentioned, you can use tables to help your users lay out their content without CSS (it makes me cringe, but yes on CMS-driven sites with users of all types editing content, I still give them a table to save me headaches).

The template plugin will allow you to set up your own table, lock it in place, and then let the users select it from a dropdown. So, you could set up a table to your specifications above, name it "2-column with dates" or something, and train your users to select that when they needed it.

The plugin also has a preview option so your users can pick and choose exactly which template they need.